# not copying mailing address(contact) into billing address(Account)

Tags: controller, trigger

this is class

```
 public class CopyAddressTriggerController {
        public static void perform(set<id> ids){
            List<Contact> con = new List<contact>([SELECT Id,name ,MailingStreet ,MailingCity, MailingState, MailingCountry  FROM Contact WHERE ID IN : ids order by LastModifiedDate Desc limit 1]);
               for(Contact temp : con) {
                   Account ac = new Account();
                   ac.BillingStreet =  temp.MailingStreet;
                   ac.BillingCity  =   temp.MailingCity;
                   ac.BillingState =   temp.MailingState;
                   ac.BillingCountry = temp.MailingCountry;

                    update ac; 

                }
            }
    }
```

---

this is trigger

```
trigger copyAddress on Contact (after update , after insert , after delete , after undelete) {
    Set<Id> Ids = new Set<Id>();
        if(Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUndelete){
            for ( Contact  con : Trigger.new) {        
                if(con.AccountId != null){
                    Ids.add(con.AccountId);
                }
             }
         }
        if(Trigger.isUpdate){
              for ( Contact  con : Trigger.new) {

                 if(con.AccountId != Trigger.oldMap.get(con.Id).AccountId ){
                     if(con.AccountId!=null )
                         Ids.add(con.AccountId);
                     if(Trigger.oldMap.get(con.Id).AccountId != null)
                     Ids.add(Trigger.oldMap.get(con.Id).AccountId);

                 }

           }
        }
        if(Trigger.isDelete){
            for (Contact  con : Trigger.old){
                if(con.AccountId != null){
                    Ids.add(con.AccountId);
                }
            }   
        }

        if(Ids.size()>0){
            CopyAddressTriggerController.perform(Ids);
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course your code doesn't work. In the method you call in the trigger you are creating new instances of the Account object inside a loop and trying to update them. You should look for the actual accounts in the system with a query, and assign the addresses on them in a separate loop, and then finally update the list in the end (outside the loop, because remember governor limits).

Please take a look at this code, for example:

```
// first you create a list to store the Account ids
List<Id> accountToSearch = new List<Id>();

// get them from the contacts
for (Contact c : Trigger.new)
{
    accountToSearch.add(c.AccountId);
}

// query in the db
List<Account> accounts = [SELECT Id, BillingStreet, BillingCity, BillingState, BillingCountry FROM Account WHERE Id IN :accountToSearch];

// iterate over the accounts and contacts
for (Account a : accounts)
{
    for (Contact c : Trigger.new)
    {
        // if a contact is set to the account then
        if (c.AccountId == a.Id)
        {
            // copy the contact's address to the account's fields
            a.BillingStreet = c.BillingStreet;
            a.BillingCountry = c.BillingCountry;
            a.BillingState = c.BillingState;
            a.BillingCity = c.BillingCity;
        }
    }
}

// finally update the account records
update accounts;
```

Comment: can you please update my code

Comment: I won't update your code, but I can say that if your trigger is on Contact, then you don't need that query. You should be using that query to get the Accounts that are referenced by the contacts in your trigger context. Then iterate over them updating the address, while storing the updated accounts on a separated list, and finally updating the list when the iteration is over.

Comment: List<Contact> con = new List<contact>([SELECT Id,name ,MailingStreet ,MailingCity, MailingState, MailingCountry  FROM Contact WHERE AccountId IN : ids order by LastModifiedDate Desc limit 1]);
        List<Account> ac = new List<Account>([SELECT Id,name ,BillingStreet ,BillingCity, BillingState, BillingCountry  FROM Account WHERE ID IN : ids]);ac[0].BillingStreet =  con[0].MailingStreet;
               ac[0].BillingCity  =   con[0].MailingCity;
               ac[0].BillingState =   con[0].MailingState;
               ac[0].BillingCountry = con[0].MailingCountry;
      update ac; }}

Comment: Please take a look at my post. I provided an example.

Comment: your code work fine... but only one mistake that billingStreet,BillingCountry,BillingState,BillingCity these are not present in contact that names start from MailingState and so on..thanks fr your effort